# How to load a combobox from another combobox?

Tags: combobox, c++builder

I have a Combobox listing the school units of my DB. My code:

```cpp
_fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)   {

  QueryUnidade->Close();
  QueryUnidade->Open();

  while (QueryUnidade->Eof == false){
    ComboBoxUn->Items->Add(QueryUnidade->FieldByName("unidade")->AsString);
    QueryUnidade->Next();
  }

}
```

In my other need combobox list the shifts that are associated with unit chosen in the first combobox, but is not showing up. My code looks like this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::ComboBoxTurnoChange(TObject *Sender)    {

  QueryTurno->Close();
  QueryTurno->ClearFields();
  QueryTurno->SQL->Add("SELECT DISTINCT TURNO FROM ALUNO WHERE UNIDADE ='"+  (Trim(ComboBoxUn->Text)+"'"));
  QueryTurno->Open();

  while(QueryTurno->Eof == false){
    ComboBoxTurno->Items->Add(QueryTurno->FieldByName("turno")->AsString);
    QueryTurno->Next();
  }
  ComboBoxTurno->Update();

}
```

Comment: 1) Stop concatenating SQL. Use parameters. 2) If nothing is showing up, your query is returning no rows. There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted (except what I mentioned in #1 above).

Comment: Yes, my query have hows, but is no showing.  
I don't need refresh for see the items of the second combobox? The combobox->Upadate() it seems is not working.

Comment: Are you sue that the event handler `ComboBoxTurnoChange` belongs to `ComboBoxUn`? I would have expected it to be `ComboBoxUnChange`. I would also disable that event while populating data in `ComboBoxUn`.

Comment: The list of comboboxTurno depends of item selected in comboboxUn.

Comment: No, you don't need to refresh after adding the items. As I said, there's nothing wrong with the code as far as adding the items. What does the debugger show you if you step through the *not Eof()* loop?

Comment: I agree with kobik, this code does make it look like the OP is trying to populate `ComboBoxTurno` when the user selects an item from `ComboBoxTurno` rather than from `ComboBoxUn`.

Comment: Exactly ... Exactly ... The problem was that my query should belongs to Event (on select) of ComboboxUn  and not to ComboxTurno

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my query should belongs to Event (on select) of ComboboxUn  and not to ComboxTurno. New code of ComboboxUn that show the result in comboxTurno, like i wanted:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ComboBoxUnSelect(TObject *Sender)
{
  QueryTurno->Close();
  QueryTurno->SQL->Add("SELECT DISTINCT TURNO FROM ALUNO WHERE 
  UNIDADE="+QuotedStr(Trim(ComboBoxUn->Text)));
  QueryTurno->Open();

 while(QueryTurno->Eof == false)
 {
    ComboBoxTurno->Items->Add(QueryTurno->FieldByName("turno")->AsString);
    QueryTurno->Next();
  }
}
```